# map_dbl fails when called with mean

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to replicate a simple example from R for Data Science, using the map functions.

This works: `map_dbl(mtcars, median)`.
But surprisingly, this doesn't: `map_dbl(mtcars, mean)`. I get this error message:

```
> map_dbl(mtcars, mean)
Error in `map_dbl()`:
i In index: 1.
i With name: mpg.
Caused by error:
! Result must be length 1, not 0.
```

This `map_dbl(mtcars, ~mean(.))`solves the problem.

But why does `map_dbl(mtcars, median)`work while `map_dbl(mtcars, mean)`doesn't?

Comment: do you have any other packages loaded?

Comment: Or perhaps you have accidentally overwritten the `mean()` function using something like `mean <- ...` somewhere in your code, e.g. `mean <- 50; purrr::map_dbl(mtcars, mean)` will result in the error you mentioned whereas `mean <- 50; purrr::map_dbl(mtcars, ~mean(.x))` still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, you've assigned another value to `mean` somewhere along the way, e.g.:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_dbl(mtcars, mean)
#>        mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
#>  20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
#>         vs         am       gear       carb 
#>   0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
map_dbl(mtcars, median)
#>     mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear 
#>  19.200   6.000 196.300 123.000   3.695   3.325  17.710   0.000   0.000   4.000 
#>    carb 
#>   2.000

mean <- list()
map_dbl(mtcars, mean)
#> Error in `map_dbl()`:
#> ℹ In index: 1.
#> ℹ With name: mpg.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! Result must be length 1, not 32.

map_dbl(mtcars, ~mean(.))
#>        mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
#>  20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
#>         vs         am       gear       carb 
#>   0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

To fix it try restarting R, making sure you aren't saving history. Or just clear out your global environment variables.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Thanks! 
Did `~mean(.)` still work because I was explicitely calling a function?

Comment: Yes, with `~mean(.)` R is looking for a function. Because you didn't assign another function to `mean` R looks in higher environments until it finds it.